# VSCode Workspace/Theme Problem - VSCode automatically changes my color theme every time I open a folder/project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been experiencing this problem for quite some time now, three years, and at this moment, it's really frustrating me. So, here's what's happening: every time I open a project in my Visual Studio Code (VSCode), the settings.json file in the .vscode folder randomly assigns colors to specific parts of the IDE window, overridig my current theme. I find this infuriating, but I recently discovered that it doesn't happen to my friends. It seems to be something specific to my account, as I always sync VSCode across every PC or Mac I use. I'm begging for someone to help me find this setting because I've searched everywhere on the internet and still haven't found a solution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dpjw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3UQ7.png)

I've tried deleting the settings.json file, but it always comes back. I tried looking at every single user and workspace setting but still didn't find any setting that actually related to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Disable all your extensions (or better, uninstall all you don't use), one of them is doing that

Something like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock may do that

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. It was an extension called Window Colors